# Only retain array rows which contain a specified value at a specified key

Tags: php, arrays, filter, exact-match

I have this function:

```
function filter($array, $like, $kol) {
    $filtered = array_filter($array, function ($item) use ($kol, $like) {
        return stripos($item[$kol], $like) !== false;
    });
    
    return array_values($filtered);
}
```

How can I modify this to only return exact values as $like? Now it searches for "like $like".

Comment: Do you mean `return $item[$kol] === $like`?

Comment: I want to search for YYY not %YYY%. YYY is just an example.

Comment: Did you try comparing the strings with `===` ?

Comment: Can you show the code with ===?

Comment: Perhaps something like this https://3v4l.org/gEI5r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [stripos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) will:

> Find the numeric position of the first occurrence of needle in the
> haystack string.

If you want to check if the value of **$item[$kol]** is equal to `$like` you can compare the strings

```
return $item[$kol] === $like
```

As you are indexing into the array, you could first check if the key exists.

*For example*

```
function filter($array, $like, $kol) {
    $filtered = array_filter($array, function ($item) use ($kol, $like) {
        if (array_key_exists($kol, $item)) {
            return $item[$kol] === $like;
        }
        return false;
    });

    return array_values($filtered);
}
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/gEI5r)

Answer (score 0):

Your task is asking how to create an indexed array of arrays where qualifying rows must contain a specified value at a specified key.

```
function filter($array, $value, $key) {
    return array_values(
               array_filter(
                   $array,
                   fn($row) => array_key_exists($key, $row) && $row[$key] === $value
               )
           );
}
```

The `array_filter()` call returns `true` (keeps the row) if the key exists and the value at that key is an exact match.